# Python tuple if statements

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tuples

Fairly new to python here,

I have a python tuple

```
reportTuple = (('Keith', 'Saturday', 10), ('Jane', 'Monday', 12))
```

and I want to print the name and the number but only if the value is Saturday. (print elements `0, 2` but only if elements 1 `value == Saturday`.)

Any ideas how to write to write an if statement to grab them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array, checking the value of the central element:

```py
for i in reportTuple: # Loop through each element of reportTuple
    if i[1] == "Saturday": # Is the day Saturday?
        print(i[0]) # Print name
        print(i[2]) # Print number
```

May I ask what the problem was here? Was it the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Updated first list with Junapa's modification:

You can do this with a list comprehension.

```
print(*("{}: {}".format(name,number) for (name, day, number) in reportTuple if day == 'Saturday'))
```

will print out

```
Keith 10
```

If you wanted to save the results of the if statement in a list, then you can do

```
['{} {}'.format(name, number) for (name, day, number) in reportTuple if day == 'Saturday']
```

which will return you

```
['Keith 10']
```

Comment: Well, it's here if he wants it. If not, there are other answer here that he can use. I really liked list comprehensions when I first started learning python so I figured I'll add a list comprehension answer too for him or for the random passerby.

Comment: Printing from inside a comprehension is bad form. Comprehensions are functional constructs - people don't expect side effects inside of them. Rather, do something like: `print(*("{}: {}".format(name,number) for (name, day, number) in reportTuple if day == 'Saturday'))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a very casual Python user so there is almost certainly some magic way to do this far more elegantly than I have, but I just tried this and it worked:

```
reportTuple = (('Keith', 'Saturday', 10), ('Jane', 'Monday', 12))
for report in reportTuple:
    if report[1] == 'Saturday':
        print(report[0], report[2])
```

prints

```
Keith 10
```